# JavaScript resolve reference from string and object

Tags: javascript

is it possible to get a reference to an object with the object itself

> obj

and the attributes in string form

> 'address.town.street'

so that at the end it resolves

> **obj.address.town.street**

i could immageine smth like the eval() function.

Comment: noooo. Do not use eval!

Comment: any quick explanation why not to use it besides it is very slow?

Comment: In general bad practice, teaches bad habits when there are good alternatives (like this one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function getValue(obj, path) {
    return path.split(".").reduce(function(obj, name){ return obj[name]}, obj);
}
```

Comment: Just remember that if any of your intermediate objects, say `town` is null or undefined, this will throw an exception.  If you have to add null-checking it gets significantly more complicated.

Comment: @ScottSauyet 'more complicated'? Simple `return obj&&obj[name]` will almost do the trick. It will return false if path element was falsy.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: You're absoultely right.  It's not much more complicated.  It won't necessarily return false, but that false-y value, but that's probably better anyway.  This is so much simpler than approaches I've done (granted the problems were more complicated), but I thought the same null-checking issues would definitely rear their ugly heads here.  Nicely done!

Comment: This is one-liner which allows You to go one step further - it returns particular falsy value (in this case `null`): `path.split(".").reduce((obj, key) => obj && obj[key] || null, obj);`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use eval. Use this instead

```
Object.prototype.nestedByString=function(reference){
    var current=this;
    path=reference.split(".");
    for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++){
        current=current[path[i]];
    }
    return current;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ACLhM/) is a demo

I suppose that if you're allergic to extending native prototypes, you can do this

```
function nestedByString(obj,reference){
        var current=obj;
        path=reference.split(".");
        for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++){
            current=current[path[i]];
        }
        return current;
}
```

Comment: Bad idea to spoil `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? It was built into the language for a reason

Comment: Well, cos another developers don't give a heck what this method is for. And this code will potencially break `for-in` loops without `.hasOwnProperty` checking.

Comment: this doesn't use a for in loop

Comment: Sure but it will affect every `for-in` loop! :)

Comment: Why would it do that? How can I fix it?

Comment: Coz your are extending Object.prototype and now every freaking object will inherit this method via prorototype chain.

Comment: I added an alternative without extending the prototype

Comment: You can fix it in modern browsers by defining non-enumerable property.  `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'nestedByString', {value: function(){/*blah*/}, enumerable: false})`

Comment: I find it somewhat amusing that this comment starts by repeating one of the modern so-called best practices about avoiding `eval` and then describes a solution that breaks another of them by updating `Object.prototype`.  (Yes I see the alternate version as well.)  It's not that I necessarily disagree, but I do find it amusing.